# check for duplicates in database php

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to check if I have a duplicate category in my database when I type a new category...Am I missing something?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['create_new_category'])) {
    $newcategory = $_POST['Add_category'];
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM JobAdCategories WHERE jacat_title ='" . $newcategory . "'" OR die(sqlsrv_errors());
    $statement1 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query1);
    $count      = sqlsrv_num_rows($statement1);
    if ($statement1 === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query):" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    }
    if ($newcategory == null) {
        echo "give category";
    } else if ($count == 0) {
        $query2     = "INSERT INTO JobAdCategories (jacat_title) VALUES ('" . $newcategory . "')";
        $statement2 = sqlsrv_query($connection, $query2);
        if ($statement2 === false) {
            echo "Error (sqlsrv_query2):" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        }
        echo "new category inserted";
    } else {
        echo "category exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: A few tips: Try to only ask specific questions that other people will also have in future. Do not include personal information (like how long you have been coding). Do not include any kind of thanks in advance, as we have better ways (upvotes and correct-answers) for showing appreciation. The rules are quite strict, but they really are important, and do ultimately benefit the whole community.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your infromation i will keep them in my mind for the future

Comment: Awesome, but you really need to edit this question to fit [the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) better. Thanks.